# Displaying image in Parse.com Javascript throws 403 (forbidden)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have uploaded images in [Parse cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3lAK.png). I'm using rest API to return the image URL to Javascript client (in Google Chrome). The image fails to load. When Inspected, the console in Chrome shows

`GET http://files.parsetfss.com/bd4945df-f61a-4e6d-99cc-9a026fbadfa3/tfss-870a44af-fc02-4271-b365-aaeb6074cc10-dominos.png/ 403 (Forbidden)`.

But when I open the URL in browser, the image appears.

I tried returning the file object instead of the URL alone but I get the same issue with fileObject.url(). Below is the code for reference

**In Javascript**

Object contains a property named icon which has the URL of the parse file

```
<img src=' + returnedObject.icon + '/>
```

**In Cloud Code**

Temp is returned

```
var temp = {};
temp.prop1 = "something"
temp.icon = parseObject.get('icon').url();
```

Comment: What if you replace this <img src=' + returnedObject.icon + '/> with this: <img src="' + returnedObject.icon + '" />

Comment: @Teddy, your suggestion worked. You may post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you replace this

```
<img src=' + returnedObject.icon + '/>
```

with this:

```
<img src="' + returnedObject.icon + '" />
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your URL. You have a trailing dash in the URL.